# Problem with running Intellij 2021 sudo command

Tags: ubuntu, intellij-idea, sudo

I installed **intellij 2021** on ubuntu today and when I start it with `sudo ./idea.sh` command It start and after a second the following logs will be appeared in terminal and its process will be killed.

```
No protocol specified
No protocol specified
No protocol specified
No protocol specified
No protocol specified
No protocol specified
No protocol specified
No protocol specified
No protocol specified
[0413/044624.403508:FATAL:gpu_data_manager_impl_private.cc(445)] GPU process isn't usable. Goodbye.
Trace/breakpoint trap
```

But when I start it without `sudo`(`./idea.sh`) everything is OK.

**Note:** I removed **Intellij 2020** today and I didn't have this problem with it.

Can anyone tell me why?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is there any good reason to run IntelliJ using `sudo` ?

Comment: After I run it without `sudo` Intellij show me a popup for every change in the files and tell,  failed to change read-only status of files.

Comment: @NicoHaase I have the same problem. Running intellij from terminal without sudo says that it is already running and quits. `sudo` forces it to open _something_ which is better I suppose.